# urllib.request from console or py file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-python-console

I tried a code to get attribute values from internet.
Line by line from console the code worked well.
As soon I was running it as Python file, QGIS crashed without comments.
Trying commenting lines out - the reason was in line that begins with

```
req=...
```

Is it usual, that code works well in console, but not as code from redactor?

```
import urllib.request

url1 = 'https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-xy.php?'
for f in er_f.getFeatures():
    pt=f.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    y=pt.x()
    x=pt.y()
    url2='x='+str(x)+'&y='+str(y)+'&d=1'
    url=url1+url2
    print(url)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    tunnus = response.read()
    print(tunnus)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssl certificates on the server seem to work not as expected for the quite outdated urllib requests module:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

I've tried your code with a working example of coordinates as no one knows the feature layer you're using and used the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module for python3.

The result works as expected even as a standalone python file:

```
import requests
url1 = 'https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-xy.php?'
test = [{"x": 6515844.06, "y":547300.83},{"x": 6515814.06, "y":547779.83}]

for f in test:
    y=f["y"]
    x=f["x"]
    url2='x='+str(x)+'&y='+str(y)+'&d=1'
    url=url1+url2
    print(url)
    req = requests.get(url)
    response = req.text
    print(response)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The new requests libray works well.